# Thymeleaf - parametrized fragment - how send data from template, to layout and then to fragment?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

please, I want ask something about parametrized fragments in Thymeleaf.
I have homepage.html , it is thymeleaf template to which I am sending Model model by Controller (Java, Spring). this model has this value: "AllComments: listOfComments".
listOfComments is varirable of type List with Comment objects in.

I want to use this "AllComments" variable in fragment "comment". (to print table). How can I send this variable from homepage.html through layout.html to fragment in fragments.html ? Thank you for answer.

```
<!-- 
 folder : ..../templates 
 homepage.html
to this template i am sending Model model with: "AllComments: listOfComments".
listOfComments is varirable of type List<Comments> with Comment objects in.
-->
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
   xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
   layout:decorate="~{layout/layoutPage.html}"
   lang="sk">
<head>
 <title>My Page</title>
</head>

<body>

<main layout:fragment="content">

</main>
</body>
</html>

<!-- 
 folder: ..../layout
 layoutPage.html  -->
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="sk"
       xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
       xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8" />
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
 </head>
 
 <body>
     
 <main layout:fragment="content"></main>
 
 <div th:replace="fragments/fragments :: comments" />
    
 <footer th:replace="fragments/fragments :: footer" />
 </body>
 </html>

 <!-- 
     folder: ..../fragments
     fragments.html -->
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="sk">
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>






<!--fragment footer-->
<footer th:fragment="footer">
 <hr>
 <p>Footer: xxx</p>
 <hr>
</footer>

<!--fragment comment-->

<div th:fragment="comments(AllComments)">

 <table class="comments">
     <thead>
     <tr>
         <th> Username </th>
         <th> Comment </th>
         <th> Commented On</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     <tr th:if="${AllComments.empty}">
         <td colspan="2"> No Comments Available </td>
     </tr>
     <tr th:each="item : ${AllComments}">
         <td><span th:text="${item.username}"> </span></td>
         <td><span th:text="${item.comment}">  </span></td>
         <td><span th:text="${item.commentedOn}"> </span></td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the variable to where you use the fragment:

```
<div th:replace="fragments/fragments :: comments(${AllComments})" />
```